# i need to now the accuracy of OpenEars, speech library for IPhone using CMUSphinx?

Tags: iphone, ipad, speech-to-text

hello
any one who have used this OpenEars, speech library for IPhone using CMUSphinx and can tell me how much it is helpful for speech to text conversion for iOS and with how much accuracy i need to attain 80% speech should be converted to text is this library can do this for me

help required

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OperEars API has its internal word storage that make it very reliable in terms of accuracy you can increase the accuracy with passage of time by adding user defined word with user's own speech that is a big feature of this API see [this](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/09/openears-speech-library-for-iphone-using-cmusphinx/)